# How to apply convention for method arguments solution-wide?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Let's say that for example, I want all arguments to start with "myarg".
Like an "id" argument should be called "myargId" and so on.
How can I apply this solution-wide and even better, possibly display it as a "warning" when someone creates a new method? You know, like underlining it and annoying the developer :P

Comment: ...why would you want that? Maybe a code analysis tool like ReSharper or StyleCop can do this for you.

Comment: I think you can write an extension for Visual Studio that does what you want

Comment: The why is a big question, let's simply say it's not my decision.. An extension you say? I was hoping I could somehow apply it as a "Code Style" somewhere in the options